# how to transfer extra data from one fragment to another through activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent

For example, In a list view hosted by **ListActivity**, when user click on a item on the list, a new activity will be launched, and previous activity transfer extra data to the new activity like below:

```
public class Notepadv2 extends ListActivity {
    ...

   @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
     }
}
```

How it should be If I use fragments? I mean if I have one Activity which host 2 fragments, and make fragments transactions like below:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

how can I transfer extra data from one fragment to the other fragment through the host activity?

I know on android developer webpage, there is a [good document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) of how to use fragment and how to communicate with activity, but there is no description about how to transfer data from one fragment to another....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Pass data(extras) to a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment)

Answer (score 22):

Use

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putString("name",value);
Fragment fragment = new nameOfFragment();
fragment.setArguments(data);
.navigateTo(fragment);
```

Comment: Do you mean I do not need to define interface in fragment and let the host activity to implement the interface which set up a communication between fragment and host acvitity... instead, I can use your code to directly navigate to the next fragment?

Comment: @its not blank Can you please shed more light on .navigateTo(fragment); android studio doesnt seem to recognize this

Comment: navigate to was my local method.