# Android: Pass data(extras) to a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm new to Android programming and I'm having problems while passing an ArrayList of a Parcelable to a fragment.
This is the Activity that is launched(working well!) where **feedlist** is an ArrayList of a parcelable **Music**.

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, ListMusicsActivity.class);

in.putExtra("arrayMusic", feedList);
activity.startActivity(in);
```

The fragment Activity onCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitymusiclist);

    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        ListMusicFragment frag = new ListMusicFragment();
        frag.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    }
}
```

The Fragment code:

```
public class ListMusicFragment extends SherlockFragment{

private ArrayList<Music> listMusics = new ArrayList<Music>();
private ListView listMusic;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    listMusics = (ArrayList<Music>) getArguments().getSerializable("arrayMusic");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.musiclistview, container, false);
    listMusic = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.musicListView);
    listMusic.setAdapter(new MusicBaseAdapter(getActivity(), listMusics));

    return view;
}
}
```

I think the problem is in the line

```
listMusics = (ArrayList<Music>) getArguments().getSerializable("arrayMusic");
```

Finally this is my Music class:

```
public class Music implements Parcelable{

private String url;
private String artist;
private String title;
private String duration;
private String info_url;
private String lyrics;


public Music(String url, String artist, String title, 
    String duration, String lyrics, String info_url)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.title = title;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.lyrics = lyrics;
    this.info_url = info_url;
}

public Music(Parcel in)
{
    url = ParcelUtils.readString(in);
    artist = ParcelUtils.readString(in);
    title = ParcelUtils.readString(in);
    duration = ParcelUtils.readString(in);
    info_url = ParcelUtils.readString(in);
    lyrics = ParcelUtils.readString(in);
}

public String getUrl()
{
    return url;
}

public String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public String getDuration()
{
    return duration;
}

public String getLyrics()
{
    return lyrics;
}

public String getInfo()
{
    return info_url;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
{
    ParcelUtils.writeString(dest, url);
    ParcelUtils.writeString(dest, artist);
    ParcelUtils.writeString(dest, title);
    ParcelUtils.writeString(dest, duration);
    ParcelUtils.writeString(dest, lyrics);
    ParcelUtils.writeString(dest, info_url);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Music> CREATOR = 
    new Parcelable.Creator<Music>() {

    public Music createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Music(in);
    }

    public Music[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Music[size];
    }
};
}
```

When I run this code the problem I get is a **java.lang.NullPointerException in the Fragment onCreateView() method**.
I would appreciate a lot if someone pointed me in the right direction to see where I am failing.

**EDIT**: Problem solved: I just needed to add this line to the fragment Activity onCreate() method(othwewise the getArguments() would return null):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();
```

And add this to the fragment code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        listMusics = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("arrayMusic");
        listMusic.setAdapter(new MusicBaseAdapter(getActivity(), listMusics));
    }
}
```

where, listMusics is an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable` Music.

Comment: The first step is going to open up the LogCat window, look at the exception and see what is causing the NullPointerException.  If you can't figure it out, then put the stacktrace from the exception into your questions o someone can help.

Comment: BrianV: Thanks for the tip! Here it is the LogCat I get when I execute the program! http://pastebin.com/ycVcXLFf

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your view layout file: ** Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment**

Comment: No, the error is in the the code of the ListView, I'm sure of it. If I create a ArrayList of Music objects in the ListMusicFragment the code works just fine. Anyway, here it is my layout files: http://pastebin.com/4DwHh1yk

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Two things. First I don't think you are adding the data that you want to pass to the fragment correctly. What you need to pass to the fragment is a bundle, not an intent. For example if I wanted send an `int` value to a fragment I would create a bundle, put the `int` into that bundle, and then set that bundle as an argument to be used when the fragment was created.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Second to retrieve that information you need to get the arguments sent to the fragment. You then extract the value based on the key you identified it with. For example in your fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}
```

What you are getting changes depending on what you put. Also the default value is usually `null` but does not need to be. It depends on if you set a default value for that argument.

Lastly I do not think you can do this in `onCreateView`. I think you must retrieve this data within your fragment's `onActivityCreated` method. My reasoning is as follows. `onActivityCreated` runs after the underlying activity has finished its own `onCreate` method. If you are placing the information you wish to retrieve within the bundle durring your activity's `onCreate` method, it will not exist during your fragment's `onCreateView`. Try using this in `onActivityCreated` and just update your `ListView` contents later.

Comment: Simple answer, awesome. Copied your code example and it worked a treat!

Comment: So... what if arguments are specified by objects implementing specific interfaces and not primitives?

Comment: If you want to use object just make sure they implement the `Parcelable` interface. `Bundle` supports adding/getting `Parcelable` so you can send those as well no problem.

Comment: Do you have a workflow for when the fragment is defined in the layout.xml of the activity? In this case I believe android will instantiate the fragment itself meaning you can't provide arguments? Personally I am using an eventbus (otto) and a producer to pass the data from the activity to the fragment.

Comment: Sure - when you define the fragment in your XML use the android:tag attribute to set a tag for that fragment. In you activity you can use FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag() to locate that fragment and then use a FragmentTransaction to replace the XML fragment with a new fragment configured the way you want. Another approach would be to use findFragmentById and simply use the android:id value of your XML fragment.

Comment: Sorry for that I don't understand why should we put the retrieve code part in `onActivityCreated` method. Do you mean that if we put the code in `onCreate` or `onCreateView` method of a fragment, the `bundle` data generated in the activity's `onCreate` method might not be prepared. Or?

Comment: The fragment method has nothing to do, because the arguments are taken since the creation of the fragment instance, they are not taken from the original extra. But probably the way he was doing it made a reference to that bundle instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `Serializable` = no boilerplate code. For passing data to other Fragments or Activities [the speed difference to a `Parcelable`](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) does not matter.

I would also always provide a helper method for a `Fragment` or `Activity`, this way you always know, what data has to be passed. Here an example for your `ListMusicFragment`:

```
private static final String EXTRA_MUSIC_LIST = "music_list";

public static ListMusicFragment createInstance(List<Music> music) {
    ListMusicFragment fragment = new ListMusicFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(EXTRA_MUSIC_LIST, music);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(...) { 
    ...
    Bundle bundle = intent.getArguments();
    List<Music> musicList = (List<Music>)bundle.getSerializable(EXTRA_MUSIC_LIST);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple why that I prefered to the bundle due to the no duplicate data in memory. It consists of a init public method for the fragment

```
private ArrayList<Music> listMusics = new ArrayList<Music>();
private ListView listMusic;


public static ListMusicFragment createInstance(List<Music> music) {
    ListMusicFragment fragment = new ListMusicFragment();
    fragment.init(music);
    return fragment;
}

public void init(List<Music> music){
    this.listMusic = music;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.musiclistview, container, false);
    listMusic = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.musicListView);
    listMusic.setAdapter(new MusicBaseAdapter(getActivity(), listMusics));

    return view;
}
}
```

In two words, you create an instance of the fragment an by the init method (u can call it as u want) you pass the reference of your list without create a copy by serialization to the instance of the fragment. This is very usefull because if you change something in the list u will get it in the other parts of the app and ofcourse, you use less memory.

Comment: In Android it's a wrong way. Because on fragment recreation (on configuration change (screen rotation) and some others) it will invoke an empty constructor, and all parameters will be lost. Use `newInstance` and `setArguments` as recommended.