# Passing image from one fragment to a another fragment and display image in that fragment

Tags: android, image, android-fragments

**First fragment from which image is selected**

```
           iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));
                String stringUri;
                stringUri = pictureFile.toString();

                FreeFragment ldf = new FreeFragment ();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Image", stringUri);
                ldf.setArguments(args);
                Log.d("Passing image", String.valueOf(args));
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

**Second fragment receiving image and displaying it**

```
 String bbb = getArguments().getString("Image");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bbb);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Its showing error in the line "String bbb = getArguments().getString("Image");"   ,  Please help me fix it

Comment: what is error on that line?

Comment: Process: com.example.siva.prep, PID: 11651
    java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: getting null pointer exception

Comment: By using log message i found that image is successfully passing , its showing error while receiving it.

Comment: try sending path of img file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send file path to next Fragment

```
String stringUri = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();

FreeFragment ldf = new FreeFragment ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Image", stringUri);
ldf.setArguments(args);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ldf).commit();
```

In your NextFragment u can receive it and set as below

```
String imgPath = getArguments().getString("Image");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(imgPath));
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: what is pictureFile

Comment: @Ratri: File pictureFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

Comment: it says required type string but got file in >>> Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(imgPath));

Answer (score 1):

Try getting your bundle in second fragment like this

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    String s = bundle.getString(key, defaulValue);
}
```

Also check this link for further references
[Passing bundle in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String strPic = bundle.getString("Image");
File picFile = new File("your file path"+strPic);
if(picFile.exists())
{           
   iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(picFile));
}
```

Comment: @Aung Hlaing , its getting error i the word "getIntent"

Comment: In fragments you can't use this

Comment: Shall we use the word Intent