# ListView onClickItemListener to get Image

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onitemclicklistener

How can i get image from ListView page to Details View page? I just can get the textview and cannot get the imageview.
Is it my coding is wrong? How can i fixed it? Please help me thanks.

this is my ListView

```
public static final String IMAGE_NAME= "com.example.weichuan.batupahatcarworkshopsfinder.workshopsId";
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<ImageUpload> imgList;
private ListView lv;
private ImageListAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list);
    imgList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading list image...");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(WorkshopsInfoActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ImageUpload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);
                imgList.add(img);
            }
            adapter = new ImageListAdapter(ImageListActivity.this, R.layout.image_item, imgList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            ImageUpload imgList = (ImageUpload) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ImageListActivity.this, DetailsOfWorkshops.class);

            String name = imgList.getName();
            String address = imgList.getAddress();
            String contact = imgList.getContact();
            String category = imgList.getCategory();
            String URL = imgList.getUrl();

            intent.putExtra("Name", name);
            intent.putExtra("Address", address);
            intent.putExtra("Contact", contact);
            intent.putExtra("Category", category);
            intent.putExtra("URL", URL);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

this is my Details View

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private TextView textViewAddress;
private TextView textViewContact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_of_workshops);
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(WorkshopsInfoActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Bundle img = getIntent().getExtras();
            final String name = img.getString("Name");
            final String address = img.getString("Address");
            final String contact = img.getString("Contact");
            final String category = img.getString("Category");
            String URL = img.getString("URL");

            final TextView textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageName);
            final TextView textViewAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageAddress);
            final TextView textViewContact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageContact);
            final TextView textViewCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageCategory);
            final ImageView textViewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

            textViewName.setText(name);
            textViewAddress.setText(address);
            textViewContact.setText(contact);
            textViewCategory.setText(category);
            textViewImage.setText(URL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting text of imageview?

```
textViewImage.setText(URL);
```

It's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4352194/2746389) but I think It's better to [re-download it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android) or [get it from internal/external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847634/passing-image-from-one-fragment-to-a-another-fragment-and-display-image-in-that).

Comment: no, that is the step i don't know how to get the image