# How to call back the image fragment to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

First of all i want make edit photo profile. i use two fragment, Accountfragment and Bottom_sheet fragment. In my problem is i want pass the selected image from library and display at Accountfragment. In Bottom_sheet fragment i have pass the String, actually my problem is to callback. i have done follow the another method but not fully show [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847634/passing-image-from-one-fragment-to-a-another-fragment-and-display-image-in-that), how to call back in secondfragment. I don't know to declare in AccountFragment. Call from method ? or just declare in onCreateView? Can anyone show how to do the method to callback image from Bottom_sheet fragment.

This `AccountFragment.class`

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
@Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);

    backbutton1 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.backbutton1);
    imgprofile = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.profileimage);
    backbutton1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    imgprofile.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    return  rootView;

}

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == backbutton1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), sidemenu.class));
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }if(view == imgprofile){
            Bottom_sheet bottom_sheet = new Bottom_sheet();
            bottom_sheet.show(getFragmentManager(), "examplebottomsheet");
        }
    }
};
```

This how i pass image from Bottom_sheet fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE){

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), AccountFragment.class);
        intent.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString());


    }
}
```

Sorry i'm newbie ,  a lot to study android

Comment: You selected the image from the `AccountFragment.class` ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz not, i selected from bottom_sheet, to pass image to account

Comment: I nedd help plssss. its more important to me.....

Comment: at `onActivityResult`, does it goes to AccountFragment, without crash?

Comment: @Ticherhaz no, it's run