# Accessing the same Fragment in Navigation Drawer clears its content

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have `Fragment` A that lets the user access `Fragment` B by the click of a button, when an action is performed on B, user is redirected to `Fragment` C to retrieve a last bit of information before returning to A.
(A -> B -> C -> A).

After doing this, if I open my `Navigation Drawer` and click on the `Fragment` I am currently on (A), its contents are gone, only the Drawer itself remains.

I can't seem to explain the reason behind this.

Here is how I conserve my `Navigation Drawer`'s `Fragment` states:

```
  // User clicks on an item in Nav. Drawer, call this method
  private Fragment checkFragmentState(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        // HOME
        case R.id.nav_home:
            if (home == null) {
                fragment = new Home();
                home = fragment;
            } else
                fragment = home;
            break;
        // SEARCH CARD
        case R.id.nav_searchCard:
            if (searchCard == null) {
                fragment = new SearchCard();
                searchCard = fragment;
            } else
                fragment = searchCard;
            break;        
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

I call this method when my user clicks on an element in the Drawer, basically it checks if the `Fragment` has already been created, if so, it saves the currently existing one and uses it to be displayed.

What could cause this odd behavior?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment).

Answer (score 0):

Just launch a new instance each time

```
// User clicks on an item in Nav. Drawer, call this method
private Fragment checkFragmentState(int itemId) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Home();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_searchCard:
            fragment = new SearchCard();
            break;    
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment();    
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Let's say I want to keep what the user has previously inputted in one fragment, how can that be done if I launch a new instance each time?
EDIT: That does solve my problem, could you explain to me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: You can put them in a `SharedPreference` or in a Sqlite database.