# Android: How to send a string data from one fragment to another fragment of the same main activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

How to send a string URL from one fragment to another within the same activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you want to pass to the fragment(According to your problem you should pass a string instad of int) :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Retrieve that information you need to get the arguments sent to the fragment.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    int i = bundle.getInt(key, defaulValue);
}
```

(*Found this answer here: [Android: Pass data(extras) to a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392261/android-pass-dataextras-to-a-fragment))

Comment: Thank you, although the same code did not work but with little alterations I achieved it ...

Answer (score 1):

A popular option now is to store the data in the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) which can be shared by multiple activities / fragments.

From the Documentation:

> This approach offers the following benefits:
>
> - The activity does not need to do anything, or know anything about this
>     communication.
> - Fragments don't need to know about each other besides
>     the SharedViewModel contract. If one of the fragments disappears, the
>     other one keeps working as usual.
> - Each fragment has its own lifecycle, and is not affected by the lifecycle of the other one. If one fragment
>     replaces the other one, the UI continues to work without any problems.

A good example can also be found in the documentation:

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val selected = MutableLiveData<Item>()

    fun select(item: Item) {
        selected.value = item
    }
}

class MasterFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var itemSelector: Selector

    private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        itemSelector.setOnClickListener { item ->
            // Update the UI
        }
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var model: SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
        model.selected.observe(this, Observer<Item> { item ->
            // Update the UI
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiples ways to do that.

Below i've listed 3 options to do what you want:

- You can use a bus, to comunicate between fragments. To do that you can use a lib called Eventbus(https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), or you can implement one using RxJava.
- Another way to communicate between fragments, you can share an object in the activity that your fragments can access.
- At last you can implement an event dispatcher em share between your scope.

Comment: Once again, the eventbus is best not to use.

Comment: It is an option, not a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a shared `ViewModel` Object, fragments will communicate by *observing* the `LiveData`.

here is a [basic example of LiveData and ViewModel](https://medium.com/@taman.neupane/basic-example-of-livedata-and-viewmodel-14d5af922d0), you can also find more information in [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)